# Spotify web api sdk

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, sdk, spotify, implementation

How to play song through spotify web api.
I have build my website using spotify web api node, a library for spotify api.
But I am not able to figure out how to play songs using that library.
I know that i need to use the SDK, but I am not able to figure out how to implement the SDK, I have tried reading the documentation of Spoitfy, but still no progress.
I am new to this, so I don't have much idea. Can someone please explain me how to make it work, or show an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of how to authenticate, connect and play songs via the Web Playback SDK [in this Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spotify-recommendations)

> The Web Playback SDK is client-side JavaScript library which allows you to create a new player in Spotify Connect and play any audio track from Spotify in the browser.